# Should I set 'name' attribute in parallel to 'ng-model'?

Tags: html, angularjs

Is there any benefit to set name attribute for HTML form fields when the `ng-model` is set?

```
 <input ng-model="form.email" name="email"'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to name form elements if you plan to use validation directives. In this case validation status objects (with error details, $valid/$invalid/$touched/$dirty/$pristine flags) are registered by name of the corresponding field on the form controller object.

So YES, you do have benefits and in most cases you indeed need fields to have a name.

Simple validation example:

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-messages.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="MainController">
  <form novalidate name="userForm">
    <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="username" required minlength="5">
    <div ng-messages="userForm.username.$error" style="color:brown" role="alert">
      <div ng-message="required">Username can't be empty.</div>
      <div ng-message="minlength">Username should be at least 5 characters.</div>
    </div>
    <pre>{{ userForm.username.$error | json }}</pre>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module('demo', ['ngMessages']).controller('MainController', function($scope) {});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ng-model and the filed name are 2 different concepts.
ng-model: tells AngularJs what model/data from model you will use
name: tells the browser the name of the field. Is indicate that if you have a name to have also the id with the same name. Same goes the other way arround.

As cgee said You don't have any benefit for using name only if you want in some point in future to automate test your solution, when you will also need to set the id.

Answer (score 0):

One potential benefit is being able to [Bind to the Form and Control State](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).  If you name inputs inside a named form, you can access properties of the form itself.  This includes validation information.

A common thing I see is a from like this (this is from that same angular documentation page).

```
<form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
  <div>
    Size (integer 0 - 10):
    <input type="number" ng-model="size" name="size"
           min="0" max="10" integer />{{size}}<br />
    <span ng-show="form.size.$error.integer">The value is not a valid integer!</span>
    <span ng-show="form.size.$error.min 
                || form.size.$error.max">The value must be in range 0 to 10!</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

This leverages some angular provided validations (`min` and `max` directives).  Then it checks the actual `$error` object of the form element itself to display validation messages.

So if you plan to interact with your form in this way, it is important to name you form and controls.